# Realizar dos consultas y mostrar resultado

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Tengo un formulario con tres campos día, mes y año:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De los cuales me muestra un resultado, como la imagen siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este resultado es solo del día lunes, lo que requiero es ver opción de poder seleccionar dos días por ejemplo Lunes y Martes del mismo mes y que me genere el resultado de la consulta.

Anexo mi query que uso para ese resultado:

```
$dia = $_POST['dia'] $mes = $_POST['mes'] $anio = $_POST['anio']
$query = "SELECT dias, fechas, SUM(carne_arabe) carne_arabe FROM base WHERE dias = '".$dia."' AND mes = '".$mes."' AND anio = '".$anio."' GROUP BY fechas"
```

Espero puedan orientarme de que manera puedo obtener ese resultado...

Comment: Podrías cambiar el select de dias por checkbox y mostrar todos, y el query cambiar la condición de días por un IN

Comment: Si siempre son solo dos días puedes poner dos campos input para el día. Si son más puedes usar un select con el atributo multiple. De todas formas en ese formulario veo un problema: hasta que no sepas año y mes no sabes que días puedes seleccionar. Me explico Febrero, bisiesto puedes elegir de 1 a 29. Febrero normal de 1 a 28, Enero de 1 al 31, Abril del 1 al 30... Yo invertiría el formulario y llenaría la lista de días de manera dinámica cuando sepa el año y el mes. En el select opino igual que  Charls

Comment: Compañero @Charls podrías ayudarme con un ejemplo, ya que lo he hecho pero no me jala... gracias

Comment: Para este caso puedes implementar el concepto de [select multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple), que te permite seleccionar varias opciones.

Comment: Hola a todos, gracias por sus comentarios, me funciono lo del select multiple, pero ahora solo me toma el ultimo registro seleccionado, no me muestra los seleccionado, pero si hago un echo si me muestra los dos datos seleccionados.. pero solo me muestra el ultimo...

Comment: Muestra el código que estás usando para mostrar los datos.